# Google Charts how to hide dynamically created series and show only one in legend?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, legend, series

I use combochart and my series are created dynamically from sql database. I'd like to hide all of them but show only the first one which represents my goal line. How can I achieve that? (I know the number of series after I build array for DataTabele and probably I'd have to build some array for series)

```
var options = {
        legend: {position: "none"},
        isStacked: true,
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: {
            1: {
                type: 'line',
                color: 'red',
                }
            },
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know the index of the column which should be visible in the legend you may dynamically create the series-option based on the columns.

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Average', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda'],
         ['2004/05',      614.6,  165,      938,         522,             998,           450],
         ['2005/06',      682,  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288],
         ['2006/07',      623,  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397],
         ['2007/08',      609.4,  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215],
         ['2008/09',      569.6,  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366]
      ]);
      

    var options = {
      isStacked: true,
      legend: {position: "top"},      
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: (function(d,i){
       var s={},c=d.getNumberOfColumns();
        for(var k=0;k<c;++k){
         s[k]=(k===i)
                 ?{type:'line',color: 'red'}
                 :{visibleInLegend:false}
        }
        return s;
      })(data,//the dataTable
        0//index of the column which should be visible in the legend
       )
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" ></div>
```

Comment: Ah, good solution. I misread the original question and thought the goal was hiding data, rather than just legend items. I see my misunderstanding, now. A minor critique if I may, but single-letter variables and in-line IIFEs in an object literal make for rather difficult to read code in an example. It's efficient, but encourages copy-paste coding rather than a deeper understanding.

Comment: Good code for me. Thank you. I was thinking something like this, but I couldn't start with the code. One more thing if you could explain me: the function syntax. How is this function called? `(function(d,i){}(data, 0))` The common way of function syntax known to me is: `function name(parameter1) {}` and then I call `name(par1)`

Comment: As mentioned by nbering, it's called IIFE([immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) , the function will be executed  via `(data,0)`

Comment: thx once again - Another useful way of solving such a problem to learn. I'm getting this now.